# Switch between voltages

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, teensy

i already posted a similar question before and i still don't know exactly how to wire up things. I will try to explain better. I have a pc power supply and a pc fan that works between 5v and 12v. All i want is with a mosfet and a teensy 3.1 change between the 5v and the 12v output of that pc supply.

I have a N Channel mosfet, but i don't know exactly how to wire it up, and i already burned myself because of the overheating of that mosfet.

The mosfet is a RFP30N06L that operates on logic level. If anyone could explain me how to wire it up.

L.E. Here is a screenshot of my wiring, but i get a constant 12V when the pin is not connected and something lower when the pin is connected.(i don't have voltage tester, but the fan goes slower, but not as slow as 5V)

[image]

Comment: This is much easier if you have a P-channel MOSFET, preferably two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what you want. By doing this you are connecting your 12v rail to 5v (minus the drop across the diode). This will cause a lot of current to flow through that MOSFET and cause it to overheat.

You want two MOSFETS, one on each voltage rail, and the teensy will only have one on at a time.

[image: Example Schematic]

Comment: Extra note: if you are determined that the teensy should only use one pin to control the voltage you can either use a MUX to select one of the two MOSFETS or a double pole double throw relay (you will need to use a MOSFET to drive the relay from the teensy).

Comment: i tried half of that circuit because i have only 1 mosfet and i get a continuos 12V. It should stop when the pin_x is set to LOW, but nothing happens. I have a led on pin_x in paralel with the mosfet to check is working and the led is blinking but the fan doesn't stop.

Comment: Never mind, i've changed the mosfet to ground instead of the 12V and it works like a charm, thanks for everything.